# Checking input fields on page load?

Tags: jquery, input, document-ready

How do I check all input boxes to see if there are values when the document loads?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var inputVal=$("input").val().trim();
   if(inputVal!=''){
   }
})
```

I would like to do an action for any input boxes that have values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way:

```
$('input, select, textarea').each(
    function(){
        var val = $(this).val().trim();
        if (val == ''){
            // do stuff with the non-valued element
        }
    });
```

On closer reading it seems the OP wanted to do something with the non-empty fields, so:

```
$('input, select, textarea').each(
    function(){
        var val = $(this).val().trim();
        if (val.length){
            // do stuff with the valued element
        }
    });
```

Comment: great the each function cycles it through

Comment: Well, I assumed that you wanted to iterate through all the `input`s? What's your actual use-case?

Answer (score 1):

```
var fields = $("input, textarea, select"), i = 0;

for(i; i < fields.length; i++){
    if(fields.eq(i).val() !='') { /* ... logic ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to create a jQuery object of inputs that do have value

```
$("input").filter(function(){
    return $(trim(this.value)) !='';                      
}).doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a loop on all the inputs with type="text'.

```
 $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

The sample html is as follows

```
​<input type="text" name="input1" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="input2" value="4"/>
<input type="text" name="input3" value="5"/>​
```

If you want to include select, or other input elements in the loop, you can do what David Thomas has suggested